# Use current class in constant declaration

Tags: ruby

```
class Cat
  SUPERSTARS = [Cat.new('John'), Cat.new('Alfred')]

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

I get an error

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

because `initialize` is not again defined.

If I put the definition on the end:

```
class Cat      
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  SUPERSTARS = [Cat.new('John'), Cat.new('Alfred')]
end
```

it works.

Is it possible to keep constant declaration on the top of the file?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use this trick:

```
class Cat
  def self.const_missing(name)
    [Cat.new('John'), Cat.new('Alfred')] if name == :SUPERSTARS
  end

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Comment: One _can_ do this, but shouldn't. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's another question ;)

Comment: Yes, it definitely is :)

Comment: `Cat.constants # => []`

Comment: @ndn I edit it, now `Cat.constants` will return constant

Comment: Also the `const_missing` approach doesn't call `super` which may totally break rails' autoloading.

Comment: yeah, my mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that class definitions are just code that gets executed when the definition is reached. It's like asking if you can access the value of a local variable that you have not yet defined.

A possible workaround is to delay the evaluation of the constant until the class body is executed. Note that it's not really worth it and it shows a working solution that shouldn't be used in practice:

```
# BasicObject for minimal amount of methods
class Retarded < BasicObject
  def initialize(&value)
    @value = value
  end

  # Make sure we remove as many methods as we can to
  #  make the proxy more transparent.
  (instance_methods - %i(__id__ __send__ __binding__)).each do |name|
    undef_method name
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    # Get the actual value
    value = @value.call
    # Suppress warnings while we traverse constants
    warn_level, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil

    traversed_modules = []
    constant_finder = -> (root) do
      constant_name = root.constants.find do |constant|
        # We undefed ==, so we need a different way to compare.
        # Given that this class should be used for constant values in place,
        #  comparing object ids does the job.
        root.const_get(constant).__id__ == __id__
      end

      if constant_name
        # Just set the constant to the actual value
        root.const_set(constant_name, value)
      else
        # Recursively search for the containing module of the constant
        root.constants.each do |child_name|
          child_constant = root.const_get(child_name)
          if child_constant.is_a?(::Module) &&
               !traversed_modules.include?(child_constant)
            # Handle circular references
            traversed_modules.push child_constant
            constant_finder.(child_constant) 
          end
        end
      end
    end

    # ::Object is the root module where constants are contained
    constant_finder.(::Object)

    # Bring back warnings
    $VERBOSE = warn_level

    # We have already found the constant and set its value to whatever was
    #  passed in the constructor. However, this method_missing was called
    #  in an attempt to call a method on the value. We now should make that
    #  invocation.
    value.public_send(*args, &block)
  end
end

# I know, the example is mononic.
class EdwardKing
  DEAD = Retarded.new { [new('I'), new('II'), new('III')] }

  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  def whoami
    "Edward #{@number} of England"
  end
end

p EdwardKing::DEAD
  # [#<EdwardKing:0x007f90fc26fd10 @number="I">, #<EdwardKing:0x007f90fc26fc70 @number="II">, #<EdwardKing:0x007f90fc26fc20 @number="III">
p EdwardKing::DEAD.map(&:whoami)
  # ["Edward I of England", "Edward II of England", "Edward III of England"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Avdi Grimm in his free episode of rubytapas called ["Barewords"](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2012/10/01/barewords/) recommends that you don't use constants directly. Instead, wrap them in a method. And when you have a method, you don't even need the constant (which in ruby is not really *constant* anyway).

So, you can do something like this:

```
class Cat
  def self.superstars
    @superstars ||= [Cat.new('John'), Cat.new('Alfred')]
  end

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

The only difference is that you now call it `Cat.superstars` instead of `Cat::SUPERSTARS`. Your code now works and looks better too! I call it a win-win. :)

Comment: also you can use less popular caller `::` and it would be like: `Cat::superstars` :)))

Comment: @AlexGolubenko: yes, I wouldn't use this syntax for the same reason: uniformness of code.

Comment: sure, it's just a joke)